# How to group records with Pandas cut()?

Tags: python, pandas

My goal is to group `n` records by 4, say for example:

```
0-3
4-7
8-11
etc.
```

find `max()` value of each group of 4 based on one column among other columns, and create a new dataset or csv file. The `max()` operation would be performed on one column, while the other columns remain as they are.

Based on the research I have made here (Stackoverflow), I have tried to customize and apply the following solution on this site on my dataset, but it wasn't giving me my expectations:

```
# Group by every 4 row until the len(dataset)
groups = dataset.groupby(pd.cut(dataset.index, range(0,len(dataset),3))
needataset = groups.max()
```

I'm getting results similar to the following:

```
Column 1  Column 2 ... Column n
0. (0,3]
1. (3,6]
```

The targeted column for the `max()` operation did not also produce the expected result.
I will appreciate any guide to tackling the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This example should help you. Here I create a `DataFrame` of some random values between 0 and 100 with step 5, and group those values in groups of 4 (`sort_values` is really important, it will make your life easier)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'value': np.random.randint(0, 100, 5)})
df = df.sort_values(by='value')
labels = ["{0} - {1}".format(i, i + 4) for i in range(0, 100, 5)]
df['group'] = pd.cut(df.value, range(0, 105, 5), right=False, labels=labels)
groups = df["group"].unique()
```

Then I create an array for max values

```
max_vals = np.zeros((len(groups)))
for i, group in enumerate(groups):
    max_vals[i] = max(df[df["group"] == group]["value"])
```

And then a `DataFrame` out of those max values

```
pd.DataFrame({"group": groups, "max value": max_vals})
```

Comment: Colonder, thanks for your quick response. I will try to work with you solution and will let you know if it works. I will get back to you soon.

Comment: Colonder, your solution actually addresses the problem, but my dataset is quite different from the random generated data you used. Thus, I had some challenges trying to apply your solution on my dataset. I instead used the former solution and assigned "False" to the right argument of the cut(), just as you did in your solution, and that solved the problem. Thank you so much for your concern and effort. I appreciate.